# Replacing footage to a video with different frame rate - how to make timeline clips not slip?

Tags: premiere, editing, framerate, adobe

When I replace a footage to another video file which has got different frame rate from the old, the clips on the timeline slip because of the frame rate change.

If I go to Modify -> Interpret footage, and set the frame rate back to the old value on the new clip, it solves the problem, but I don't know if it's the right way to do it, or if it affects the final quality of my movie. After all, I want the clip to have its own frame rate in my sequence (the sequence frame rate matches the new clip's value).

How can I overcome this problem?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get what you're describing, but here are some ideas:

- Right click on your clip in the timeline and select the "Speed/Duration" option. Have fun.
- If you want that added clip to have its own frame rate within your sequence, perhaps you should start seeing it as an effect. So treat it as such: once your edit is done (picture lock), import it in After Effects, treat the portion of it that you need as you see fit. Export it thus transformed. Import that new clip in your timeline, place it over its old version and never worry again about a change of frame-rate.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the problem you are having either (and nofare may have answered), but whenever I hear the "timeline slip" I think of when my video gets out of sync from the audio.

My number one cause of this is having an audio layer locked when inserting a clip.

Quickest solution is to right click the red box in top right corner of clip (showing negative or positive number) and choose either "Move into Sync" or "Slip into Sync".

Sorry if this isn't your problem...just taking a stab at potential issue.